# Generated fields aren't matching what I have defined in my entity

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql-spqr

I am creating a Kotlin Spring-Boot api with a GraphQL interface.  I am facing an issue when accessing one of my entities through GraphQL. Below you can most of my setup for accessing the user object.

The issue is coming from the generated fields in GraphQL, it isn't matching what I have defined in my entity. This is only happening on the field `isAdmin` (and similarly styled ones). The output gets changed to `admin` and I cannot access it as `isAdmin`. It's not happening if I name the field like `inAdmin`, `letAdmin` or even `admin`. Its a very vague problem and I cannot seem to find any documentation on it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
class User(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    var id: Long,

    @Column(name = "user_type")
    var type: String,

    @Column(name = "is_admin")
    var isAdmin: Boolean
)
```

Resolver implementation for returning all users

```
@GraphQLApi
@Component
class UserResolver {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var userService: userServiceInterface

    @GraphQLQuery()
    fun getUsers(): List<UserType> {
        return userService.getUsers()
    }
}
```

Service Interface for storing custom queries

```
interface userServiceInterface {
    fun getUsers(): List<User>
}
```

GraphQL gui output schema

```
user{
    id
    type
    admin //<-- invalid, expecting isAdmin
}
```

Edit: A workaround right now is to use alias

```
user{
    id
    type
    isAdmin: admin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring, all variables like `isSomething` are replaced by `something` in the json.

To make it explicit, you can use a `@JsonProperty` annotation

Your class will be

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
class User(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    var id: Long,

    @Column(name = "user_type")
    var type: String,

    @JsonProperty("isAdmin")
    @Column(name = "is_admin")
    var isAdmin: Boolean
)
```

I am not sure why it happens. I'll look for the answer and edit the post when I find.

Comment: I did come by this method while I was doing some research but it seems like it isn't affecting the serialization. I've even tried GSON's `@SerializedName()` but it isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all JavaBean properties are named by their property name, not their accessor name. So `getSomething` will get mapped as `something` and `isAdmin` (that returns a `boolean`) will get mapped as `admin`. This is in line with the behavior of most frameworks/languages/serialization formats. You'll get the same default behavior when mapping to JSON, accessing the field via SpEL, mapping to DB column names etc.

To override the name on case-by-case basis, add `@GraphQLQuery` to the field (affects both input and output types) or accessor/getter (affects output types only). To affect the input type only add `@GraphQLInputField` on the field or mutator/setter. `@JsonProperty` is also respected for input types, and can optionally be configured for outputs.

You can also globally configure the naming strategy. Will post an example later.